# Ordered pair satisfying the equation $x^2 + 6x + y^2 = 4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many ordered pairs of integers $(x,y)$ satisfy the equation $x^2+6x + y^2 = 4$?

I can't approach this problem. Please help me.

Comment: Thanks for editing it for me, @Josue Tonelli-Cueto.

Comment: Do you know the technique of completing the square?

Comment: No, will you explain it to me?

Comment: For all integer $x\gt0$, there is no $y$ that satisfy $y^2=-x^2-6x+4$. So, the only solution is $(0, 2)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: You can "complete the square" - the object of which is to get rid of the $6x$ term which is awkward.

$$x^2+6x+y^2=x^2+6x+9-9+y^2=(x+3)^2+y^2-9$$

This transforms your original equation into the sum of two squares equals a positive integer. You then have only a few cases to try (remembering that integers can be negative).

Comment: There is a typo in the power of $(x+3)$. It must be 2 instead of 3.

Comment: @rugi Thanks - corrected

Answer (score 5):

By completing the square we get $(x+3)^2+y^2=13$.

If $x$ and $y$ are integers, so are $x+3$ and $y$ so we require two square numbers that add to $13$. The only option is $9$ and $4$. We can choose which is $9$ and which is $4$ as well as whether we use the positive or negative square roots. Hence $8$ possibilities.

Comment: Thanks, John. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at $f(x) = 4-x^2-6x$ you will see that $f(x) \ge 0 $ **iff** $x \in
[-3 -\sqrt{13}, -3+\sqrt{13}]$.

There are only a few integer $x$ values to try $\{-6,...,0\}$.

Any solution is of the form $y^2 = f(x)$.

Comment: How do you get the range of the values of x?

Comment: If $f(x)<0$ there is no solution, so we must have $x$ lie in the interval above. The only integral values of $x$ are the ones shown above.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. The equation $f(x) = 0$ is a quadratic equation in $x$. Use the standard formula to compute the roots.

Comment: Okay. I get it.

Comment: (There are eight solutions.)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for it.

Answer (score 1):

For all integer $x\gt0$, there is no $y$ that satisfy $y^2=-x^2-6x+4$. So, the only solutions are $(0, 2)$ and $(0, -2)$. For integer $x\lt0$, do the same and look for which $x$, the quadratic equation $-x^2-6x+4\ge0$ which are $x\in\{-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1\}$. Find $y$ now.